# Can the wording of the Abstract be modified during the prosecution phase, if it only adds matter already in the specifications?

Tags: abstract

I would like to include mention of a secondary feature that's fully described in specifications and claims, but not currently mentioned in the abstract. Process is currently at the stage of pending response to 2nd OA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be amended in the same way as any part of the specification.

[MPEP § 714 II.B](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s714.html) makes this clear, and even provides details of the format. It provides:

> Specifically regarding amendments to the abstract of the disclosure, where the amendments to the abstract are minor in nature, the abstract should be provided as a marked-up version under 37 CFR 1.121(b)(2)(ii) using strike-through and underlining as the methods to show all changes relative to the immediate prior version. Where the abstract is being substantially rewritten and the amended abstract bears little or no resemblance to the previously filed version of the abstract, a new (substitute) abstract may be provided in clean form accompanied by an instruction for the cancellation of the previous version of the abstract.

As an aside, I would note that it is pretty unusual to amend the abstract, since the applicant doesn't really get any benefit from it: it just risks further issues being raised for no gain.